# Where do you find melons?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm trying to find some melons on Xbox one I survival. I am making potions but can't find any melons whatsoever!! Can anyone give me any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find a village the villagers may have melon seeds to trade, 
chests in abandoned mineshafts may contain melon seeds or bonus chests at spawn. 
You should grow them using seed's since finding them naturally spawned is quite rare.

> Additionally they'll spawn in a jungle biome. If you've been lucky enough to have one appear on your map and know where it is search through it.

Thanks [David Gillen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/119387/david-gillen)

Comment: Additionally they'll spawn in a jungle biome. If you've been lucky enough to have one appear on your map and know where it is search through it.

Comment: I don't know how sorry, if you tell me how I will. :p @ModCloud

Comment: @Lottiefer I believe you already have :) The green tick shows you have accepted the answer

Comment: Oh ha ha. I didn't realise I pushed a green tick! I feel so stupid!!! Thanks for your help!! @ModCloud

Comment: @Lottiefer Any time dude